# Как сделать кнопку запуска для

Tags: linux

Каким образом создать кнопку запуска на рабочем столе с правами от rootфайла запуска VPN расположенного в /etc/ppp/peers/xxxx наподобие ярлыка в Windows, и второйаналогичный вопрос как запустить от root напр.krusader Alt + F2 + ??? --- какую командунужно вводить для root?

Answer (score 3):

Зависит от того какая авторизация `su` или `sudo` у Вас установлена

при установленных `gksu` или `gksudo` команда запуска будет выглядеть так

```
gksu /etc/ppp/peers/xxxxgksu .krusader
```

или

```
gksudo /etc/ppp/peers/xxxxgksudo .krusader
```

соответственно... это же можно вставить в "кнопку запуска" на рабочем столе.

Comment: Дело в том,что это уже испробовано--не работает!!!  Почему не знаю, есть ли другие способы?Система CentOS 6

Comment: A Gtk+-based 'su' wrapperGKSu is a stack of libraries and an application that provide a Gtk+ frontend to su and sudo. It supports login shells and preserving environment when acting as a su frontend. It is useful to menu items or other graphical programs that need to ask a user's password to run another program as another user.Это отдельный пакет....установка'su' или 'sudo apt-get install gksu'аналогично для 'gksudo'

Comment: К сожалению не идет

Comment: "не идёт" - это не понятно ( ( (ругается? не может чего-то найти? поподробнее напишите....

Comment: см.выше  --ругается не идет какая разница смысл-то один gksu gedit                     |bash: gksu: команда не найдена |                               |-----из терминалаgksudo gedit                   | bash: gksu: команда не найдена |Подробности: Не удалось выполнить процесс-потомок «gksudo (gksu)» (Нет такого файла или каталога)            | --- из desktopyum install gksu 0 packages excluded due to repository protectionsSetting up Install ProcessNo package gksu available.Error: Nothing to doаналогично и с gksudoNM не использую, только вручную - надежнее да и знаешь что-где

Answer (score 1):

А чем sudo не угодил?

1. Если в системе есть networkmanager, то лучше через него все настроить!
2. Мой Гном не хочет скрипты запускать, но можно так

-

```
sudo /etc/ppp/peers/xxxx
```

Или создать интерфейс в `/etc/sysconfig/network/pppiface` и запускать `ifup pppiface`.

Comment: есть ситуации когда решение необходимо именно в определённом "ключе" - например, надо сделать это на клиентской машине, которая находится в далеко расположенном офисе, куда увы не наездишься, и пользователи там в терминале - команды вводить не будут... и тд и тп. Решений великое множество, но увы не всегда подойдёт любое ( ( (

Comment: определенно networkmanaget поможет, все через гуи будит !

Comment: с Network Manager имеется печальный опыт не хочется наступать на грабли вновь

Comment: частично да , если пк как сервер то манагера использовать не стоит, если пк рабочая станция то нормально. У меня работало 3G и VPN через него там даже есть кнопка как hotplug подключаешь модем интерфейс сам поднимается.

Comment: Решение найдено! Все очень просто оказалось,вместо gksu - gksudo нужно использовать команду kdesu.Теперь все на месте.Спасибо всем.